# Outgoing emails not being sent from workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I created a simple issue tracking list. when completed it should send the details to the person in the to: field.
Problem is when workflow completes I get this error: system account - The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly.

We have checked our smtp settings firewall etc.. setup the email address and it still isn't working. What else could be the issue??? I can't seem to find anything that works thanks

Comment: The system account doesn't have any e-mail address

Comment: how do you change it to come from another email address then system in the workflow?  IT doesn't have system setup with an email address and says to use another account how do you do that

Comment: Oh are you running everything as system? Do you have an option to setup stuff using service accounts instead?

Comment: I believe so, i'm a programmer and IT set this up. I believe they said system doesn't have email or anything and need to use a service account. I think we do but how do you set that up and have the workflow use the service account and not system? i'm new to this